# Purchase cancelled from Google Play Store, but verification fee deducted

Tags: google-play-store, in-app-purchase

Yesterday I was trying to purchase an app from the Play Store. So I added my card details to the dialog window that appeared, and Google deducted a small sum from my A/C (Rs.51 INR), which I know, is for the purpose of verification of my card. But the problem is, the app which I was trying to purchase says the transaction was cancelled. Here's the transaction log from [Google Payments](https://payments.google.com):

> Sep 1 » Google has canceled this purchase.
>
> Comments from Google: Your credit card ending in XXXX was declined.
>
> Please select a different payment method.
>
> Sep 1 » Your XXXX-XXXX was declined for this purchase.

If I entered wrong credentials, then why did the verification amount got successfully deducted?

Should I attempt to make the purchase again?

Answer (score 0):

The verification fee is refunded to the account within 3-7 business days.

Check this for details.
[Google Play deducted extra Rupee 50 after first-time Play Store purchase of an App/Game. Why is that?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/48948/google-play-deducted-extra-rupee-50-after-first-time-play-store-purchase-of-an-a)

Comment: I know that already. Please read the question again.

Comment: Don’t take it personally, but does your card have balance? Also u sure the credentials was the only reason for the decline?

Comment: In order to determine if a card exists or is chargeable a small transaction has to be completed against the card. Normally for a 'validation' check this would take the form of a very small 'preauthorization' transaction, which requires a clearing bank, connections to credit card providers and all manner of expensive things. Google being a well-recognized company, they have all the resources required to perform this check while being in the legal guidelines(they are not deducting money forever).

Comment: Yes. I do have enough balance in my account.